# Facebook friends list data is always nil but count is 412?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

// I have already got approval from facebook

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                    initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                    parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

       [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                            NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                            for (NSDictionary* friend in friends) {
                                                NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@",[friend objectForKey:@"name"]);
                                            }
                                        }];
                                    }
                                }];
```

//Please review

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need approval for the `user_friends` permission, you only need to authorize users with it to get access to friends. You´ve already done that correctly if you get the friend count.

To your main question: You can only get access to friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too. That´s why the list is empty.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)